# How to read file path from a column?

Tags: excel, vba

Every time there is a data entry in column D, I want a text file (a note) to be created in a folder with all my other notes. The file path together with the name is in column C.

How do I read the file path from a column?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("D:D")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then
        Dim fso As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim fileOut As Object
        Set fileOut = fso.CreateTextFile("THIS/SHOULD/BE/a/cell/reference.txt")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the corresponding cell is in the same row as the cell that was just edited, it would look like this:

```
Set fileOut = fso.CreateTextFile(Range("C" & Target.Row).Value2)
```

Here you could also use `Range("C" & Target.Row)` and it would still give you the value in the cell, but it's better if you can already get used to `.Value2` as it is the more reliable and faster way to retrieve the value of a cell.

Here is a blog post that discuss why you should use `.Value2` instead of the default `.Value` : [Blog post](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Comment: Thank you very, very much!!! It works perfectly!!! And thanks for the blog post, I'll check it out! Have a nice day! I'm sorry that my vote is not recorded! amazing!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I encourage you to look at the many tutorials available online if you want to learn more about the wondrous world of VBA programming.